# Запуск программ по расписанию

Tags: java, android

Нужно реализовать возможность запуска программ по расписанию. Как это можно сделать? Буду рад подробному плану реализации)) Ссылки с примерами приветствуются)

Comment: по сути, вам нужен "будильник", который вместо воспроизведения мелодии будет делать что-то другое? http://android-helper.com.ua/alarm/

Comment: @metalurgus получается, что да. вместо мелодии нужно запускать какое-то другое приложение.

Comment: на данном сайте ссылки на сторонние ресурсы вообще не приветствуются

Answer (score 6):

Вам необходимо:

1. Создать BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver, который будет запускать основной сервис после загрузки устройства.
2. Создать AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver, который будет запускаться каждые N минут и запускать основной сервис. Затем он будет ставить себя в расписание
3. Создать главный сервис AppService extends IntentService, который будет смотреть, пора запускать какое нибудь приложение или ещё нет.
4. Создать главное Activity, которое будет первый раз стартовать AlarmReceiver и AppService.

В качестве примера, есть аналогичное приложение https://github.com/grow2014/Mobile-Traffic-Statistic.
Приложение просыпается через заданное время, считает израсходованный трафик и отправляет информацию на сервер. Плюс запускается после перезагрузки. Вам нужно сделать только вместо отправки информации свои действия.

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: Да, спасибо. Главное, что есть за что зацепиться.